# React onClick and onTouchStart fired simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div in my React app and I need to handle both clicks and touches. However, when I tap on a mobile, it fires both events.

If I swipe on a mobile or if I click on a normal browser, it works fine, only one event is fired in each case.

How can I handle this tap issue to not fire both events?

```
<div
  className={myClasses}
  onClick={this.myHandle}
  onTouchStart={this.myHandle}
  >&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need both TouchStart and click? click will be called both for mobile and desktop.
The lifecycle is usually: touchstart (mousedown) -> touchend (mouseup) -> click.
so unless you need to do something explicit for touchstart I'd just drop it.

Comment: I got your point. I had just one of the before, however, if the user swipes, it won't fires the click, only touch events. This is kind of a carousel, where the user can click or swipe the "next card" in order to slide.

Comment: All my experience with these controls tells me that these do not fire at the same time?? Are you certain you're analysing the situation correctly?

Does event.preventDefault() help you here?

Comment: @Shammoo I mean they are fired with the same mouse action. When I tap, both events are fired, first `onTouchStart` and then `onClick`. My handle `this.myHandle` changes the state, so the component renders again. And the second event (click) still fires.

Comment: For people who find this in the future: that's what it's supposed to. `onClick` is not a "mouse" event, it's a "click" event, and is equivalent to "touchStart-followed-by-touchEnd` on touch devices. So on a touch device, `touchstart` fires, calls the handler, `touchend` fires, has no handler, and then `click` fires, calling the handler again. Just remove `onTouchStart`, and you're done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved this problem using similar events between touch and mouse. touchStart/mouseDown or touchEnd/mouseUp. It fires one or another, according to each situation.

```
<div
  className={myClasses}
  onMouseUp={this.myHandle}
  onTouchEnd={this.myHandle}
  >&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the `this.myHandle` function?

Answer (score 17):

There is a defined order of when the events get fired ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent#Event_order)):

```
touchstart
Zero or more touchmove events, depending on movement of the finger(s)
touchend
mousemove
mousedown
mouseup
click
```

If you want to prevent a `click` event if a touch event is fired before, you can you can use `event.preventDefault()` in the `touchend` [event handler](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-event-handler/) to prevent the `click` event from firing.

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    alert('click');
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = (event) => {
    alert('touchend');

    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
      onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
    >
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```

However, this is not universally applicable. For example, you cannot [prevent](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault/) a `click` event by using a `event.preventDefault()` in a `mousedown` event. In case you are looking for a solution to this (not sure when this use case applies though), you would have to use a [ref](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-ref/) instead:

```
function App() {
  const prevent = React.useRef(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!prevent.current) {
      alert('click');
    } else {
      prevent.current = false;
    }
  };

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    prevent.current = true;

    alert('mousedown');
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
    >
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: In React I had to do `event.stopPropagation()` to stop it from firing both `onTouchStart` and `onMouseDown`

Answer (score 2):

This is a few years late but found a solution that was really easy to implement. Looks like this:

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class YourClass extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('touchstart', (e)=>{ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            console.log("touchstart triggered");
        });
    }
}
```

Seems like it intercepts and stops all onClick calls on mobile which is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `onClick()` on touch devices you should check if the page is opened in touch devices or not. 
To check weather it is opened in touch devices or not:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
}
```

Then modify `{isTouch ? undefined : this.myHandle}` to your mouse event:

```
<div
  className={myClasses}
  onClick={isTouch ? undefined : this.myHandle}
  onTouchStart={this.myHandle}
  >&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: It's sketchy, because some devices handle both mouse and touch.